# Google Colab: How to use LateX fonts in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

Following the suggestions [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html), I thought I could include the following code snipped to render latex fonts in matplotlib

```
plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "Computer Modern Roman"
})
```

To make sure latex was installed, I also ran `!pip install latex`. I am running Google Colab on Windows 11.

Yet, this is the error I received:

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/root/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/41e3affc34550e765935caf5a875fad6.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `type1ec.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.6 \usepackage
               {type1ec}^^M
No pages of output.
Transcript written on 41e3affc34550e765935caf5a875fad6.log.
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Run this code in Google colab, it will work

```
plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'STIXGeneral'
```